# Why doesn't program in /system/app get SuperUser access?

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

We are creating an Android application which requires super user privileges. The SuperUser.apk and su are installed. However there seems to be a difference between installing our application in /data/app vs. /system/app. If we install in /data/app, everything seems to work fine. If we install in /system/app, SuperUser.apk does not popup to grant privileges.

Are there certain types of programs that must be installed in one location vs. another?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

APK files in the /system/app folder already have system-level permissions so they don't require SuperUser, which I assume is why it doesn't pop up.

You should confirm that your application already has the permission you have requested. For instance, [AlarmManager.setTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setTime%28long%29) requires the signatureOrSystem permission android.permission.SET_TIME and will throw an exception if it doesn't have it. You can also check explicitly with [PackageManager.checkPermission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#checkPermission%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

If this doesn't work, check the attributes of the APK file. If they don't match the other APKs in the system folder Android may ignore them. You can fix it like this:

```
chmod 644 <filename>
```

Comment: Should that be `chmod` rather than `CHMOD`?

Comment: @KeithThompson You're right of course - I've edited the answer.